# Find if website is using specific HTML elements in popup

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm trying to detect whether a website popup contains a specific HTML element.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
driver.get('http://www.google.com/')
elements = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "div")
time.sleep(10)

new_elements = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "div")
if elements != new_elements:
    print('Smth new')
else:
    print('Nothing new')
```

The problem is that I do not get 'Smth New' even tho this website has a popup that creates new div elements.

Here is the popup screenshot
[image]
Could you please tell me what am i doing wrong?

Comment: The amount of DIVs are same for both variables `elements` and `new_elements`. That is why you see `Nothing new`. Could you please add a screenshot with popup? because I don't see any new popup when open google's search page.

Comment: Done, not sure if u are notified about question changes

Comment: As I don't have this popup I can't tell for sure, but I suppose popup is there already (inside html DOM) after page is loaded. And after a few seconds it appears because for example javascript makes it visible (by changing 'css' styles). You can verify this theory by getting this `div` by id (or somehow else, like xpath, or css selector) right after you load the page first time. But I would suggest to simply press 'confirm cookies' button (using Selenium) and go further to your desired flow/scenario.

Comment: You are right, I found it right after page is loaded, so I guess it's just hidden. 
My final goal is to check whether page using popups contains `form` inside a popup. It's a counter phishing project. I thought the easiest way to test whether I'm using Selenium right, is to check div number on website. So I understand there is no way I distinguish form on the actual page from form in hidden pop up elem, right?

Comment: Honestly, I don't know. But in general I guess Selenium is not quite right tool to check such kind of things (at least I am not aware of such usage of Selenium).

Comment: I see, thank you for your time. I will try to find other solution